# SpringBoot @DateTimeFormat and custom error message via MessageSource

Tags: spring, spring-boot, datetime-format, java-time, custom-errors

I'm trying to avoid return this kind of error to the client when the Spring fails to convert a date using @DateTimeFormat

> Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to
> required type 'java.time.LocalDateTime' for property 'myDate'; nested
> exception is
> org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to
> convert from type [java.lang.String] to type
> [@org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat
> java.time.LocalDateTime] for value '2023-01-01 00:00'; nested
> exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed
> for value [2023-01-01 00:00]

This is what I tried.

```
public class MyDTO {

  @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
  private LocalDateTime myDate;
}
```

A Controller

```
@GetMapping("/hello")
public String test(@ParameterObject MyDTO myDTO) {
    return "hello";
}
```

In the `messages.properties` file I have added (added different combinations just to test)

```
typeMismatch.java.time.LocalDateTime=Date is not correctly formatted
typeMismatch=Date is not correctly formatted
```

I also have a Controller advice

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyControllerAdvice {

@ExceptionHandler(BindException.class)
  public ResponseEntity<....> handleBindException(BindException e) {
   // I break point in here to see what's inside e and verify my custom error code is in there somewhere
  }
}
```

If I call the controller with a wrong date such has `2023-01-01 00:00`, Spring correctly throws a BindException containing the original exception details and the following error `codes`

```
typeMismatch.java.time.LocalDateTime
typeMismatch.MyDTO.myDate
typeMismatch.myDate
typeMismatch
```

But my custom error message is no where to be seen. The only way to get it is to manually `@Autowired MessageSource messageSource` (which is automatically created by SpringBoot using the `ResourceBundleMessageSource` implementation and call `messageSource.getMessage(code, args, locale)` OR `messageSource.get((MessageSourceResolvable) e.getBindingResult().getFieldError().getArguments()[0], locale)`

Now from reading various SO on the subject, people seem to say that by just adding the custom error message in the `messages.properties` it should magically adds these error message somewhere in the exception but I cannot see this kind of code anywhere in the spring code base (DefaultMessageCodesResolver? DefaultBindingErrorProcessor ? `org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.TemporalAccessParser where the actual` DateTimeParseException `is thrown` ?

Did I just read these answers wrong and whatever we add in the `messages.properties` needs to be manually fetched using `messageSource.getMessage(code, args, locale)` from the Controller Advice ?

Comment: did you tried to unwrap the error messages in the `ControllerAdvice` and put them into the `ResponseEntity`?